# Get Magento Session in Directory that is outside Magento

Tags: magento, session, directory

I want to get customer session in a dir which is outside of my magento main dir. For e.g. root/magento/  => is my installation dir
root/temp/  => is my test folder
root/checksession.php => is the file on root of magento installation
root/temp/checksession.php => is the file outside of magento dir and inside of external dir.
Here i am getting the customer session in root/checksession.php but i dont know why the same coding is not working with root/temp/checksession.php
Have tried include, define and php session method, but still its not working.

Do any one have idea, how it is possible to get magento session in root/temp/checksession.php file???

```
require_once 'app/Mage.php';
Mage::app("default");
$coreSession = Mage::getSingleton('core/session', array('name' => 'frontend'));
session_start();
$_SESSION["coreSession"] = $coreSession;
echo "<pre>";print_r($coreSession);
```

Comment: what says `print_r($coreSession);`? Are there any errors? Do you include `Mage.php` as shown above or like `require_once '../app/Mage.php';`?

Comment: try to add `error_reporting(E_ALL | E_STRICT);
ini_set('html_errors', 1);
Mage::setIsDeveloperMode(true);
ini_set('display_errors', 1);`

Comment: Check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22485694/magento-customer-login-programmatically/22487635#22487635

Comment: I am adding require_once 'app/Mage.php'; in root file, and require_once '../app/Mage.php'; in temp dir file

Comment: after adding Mage::setIsDeveloperMode(true); ini_set('display_errors', 1);                                                                                                                                               ( ! ) Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Exception' with message 'Warning: simplexml_load_string():

Answer (score 0):

I think you forgot the following:

```
Mage::app('admin')->setUseSessionInUrl(false);
```