# Magento login a customer programmatically

Tags: php, magento

I am trying to login a customer programmatically in magento.
I have followed [this tutorial](https://blog.ancud.de/home/-/blogs/magento-how-to-login-a).

So I created a file named test.php in the root of my magento app.

```
<?php



require_once 'app/Mage.php';

 function loginById($customerId)
{
    Mage::app(); // to make sure that Mage::getModel() works


 $customer = Mage::getModel('customer/customer')->load($customerId);
    if ($customer->getWebsiteId()) {
        Mage::init($customer->getWebsiteId(), 'website');
        $session = Mage::getSingleton('customer/session');
        $session->loginById($customerId);
        return $session;
    }
    throw new Exception('Login failed');
}

    try {
    $session = loginById(1);
    //echo Mage_Customer_Model_Session::isLoggedIn();exit;
   // var_dump($session);exit;
            // function login() from above
    $session->setAfterAuthUrl(
            'http://192.168.1.61/magento/index.php/customer/account');
    //echo $session->getAfterAuthUrl();exit;
    header('Location: ' . $session->getAfterAuthUrl());

} catch (Mage_Core_Exception $e) {
    echo "error";
}
```

But when I access this file, it redirect me to login form.

Comment: Your `Mage::init()` work correctly ? In memory, the params is `Mage::init(STORE_ID, SCOPE, array());`

Comment: You doesn't catch any `Mage_Core_Exception` ? Can you place a `die;` after `echo "error";` for test this ?

Comment: Does the customer with id = 1 exist ?

Answer (score -2):

Try this one

```
<?php
function loginUser( $email, $password )
    require_once ("app/Mage.php");
    umask(0);
    ob_start();
    session_start();
    Mage::app('default');
    Mage::getSingleton("core/session", array("name" => "frontend"));

    $websiteId = Mage::app()->getWebsite()->getId();
    $store = Mage::app()->getStore();
    $customer = Mage::getModel("customer/customer");
    $customer->website_id = $websiteId;
    $customer->setStore($store);
    try {
        $customer->loadByEmail($email);
        $session = Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->setCustomerAsLoggedIn($customer);
        $session->login($email, $password);
    }catch(Exception $e){

    }


  } 
?>
```

Comment: copied from http://stackoverflow.com/a/22497102/219986 and the OP isn't using the password