# if customer logs in wordpress he automatically gets logged in into magento also

Tags: wordpress, magento, content-management-system

if customer logs in wordpress he automatically gets logged in into magento also
although the customer email id and password is entry when sign up in magento as well as word press and work properly in case of sign up but when i want to login its not working in magento.

Here attached the image

I have already try
this code
         require_once ( "shop/app/Mage.php" );
         umask(0);

```
      Mage::app("default");

       $session = Mage::getSingleton("customer/session");

       // Check if user is logged in
         if($session->isLoggedIn())
         {
         // Yes user is logged in
           echo "Yes user is logged in";
         }else{
      $session = Mage::getSingleton('customer/session', array('name' =>          'frontend'));
       $session->login("$email", "$password");
     $session->setCustomerAsLoggedIn($session->getCustomer());
      }
```

Comment: Do you get any errors? Or is the user just not logged in magento?

Comment: i did not get any error.

Comment: So.. when you sign up in wordpress the user is logged in both or just registerd ? Provide more informations please. Are you using any plugins?

Comment: When sign up the user register both but logged in only wordpress not in magento. i am not using any plugin

Comment: i want something that if user logged in wordpress then he can automatically logged into magento.

Comment: Did you tried this? _http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22485694/magento-customer-login-programmatically_

Answer (score 0):

After you logged into wordpress you can force the user-logged-state with the mail-address.

```
    Mage::getSingleton('core/session', array('name' => 'frontend'));
    $_customerExist = Mage::getModel('customer/customer')
                ->getCollection()
                ->addAttributeToSelect('*')
                ->addAttributeToFilter('email', $_mail)
                ->getFirstItem();
                $_customer = Mage::getModel('customer/customer')
    ->load($_customerExist->getentity_id());

    if(!Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->isLoggedIn()) {
      $session = Mage::getSingleton('customer/session', array('name' => 'frontend'));
      $session->setCustomer($_customer);
      $session->setCustomerAsLoggedIn($_customer);
    }
```

If you want to login with the password you can find a solution here:

[See here.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22485694/magento-customer-login-programmatically)

Whats going wrong with your version? Take a look into your logs why the login fails.

Comment: Thanks Daniel this is not my issue, i want single time to logged in and acess WordPress and magento